# Input validation help - adds extra input to next variable

Tags: c++

I'm working through a C++ course, and the only thing I'm really struggling with is input validation.

If you input a negative number, or anything but a number, you get the error, but if you input something like `24a`, it will take `24` as valid input for the first input, then take `a` and apply it to the next input.

How do I get it to show my invalid error message if ANY part of the input doesn't match?

```cpp
int rentFunction () {
    int rent;
    int rentChecked;
    bool valid = false;
    while (!valid) {
        cout << "Rent: " << endl;
        cin >> rent;
        if ((rent < 0) || (cin.fail())){
            cout << "Please enter a number of at least 0" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        } else {
            rentChecked = rent;
            valid = true;
        }
    }
    return rentChecked;
}
```

Comment: More info:
The next input question is "gas" so if you do 24a it takes 24 for rent then takes a and applies it to gas. I need it to not do either. 
I have the same loop for gas so the "a" causes an instant error message but if you were to put in 24.15 it will take the .15 and apply it to gas as valid so that also wont work. 

Oh and the cin.ignore..1000.. is there because I can't get it to work any other way so any extra tips with that would be great.

Comment: FYI, the preferred way to validate if `cin >> rent` is successful is `if (cin >> rent)`, not checking `fail()` after the fact, and certainly not after checking `rent` which may not even have a valid value assigned to it. In your example, `if (!((cin >> rent) && (rent >= 0))){` would be more appropriate than `cin >> rent; if ((rent < 0) || (cin.fail())){`, though this doesn't really answer your question. I'm just pointing it out for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are asking for, don't use `operator>>` to read in an `int`, read in a `string` instead and then validate it yourself afterwards, such as with `std::stoi()` or equivalent, eg:

```cpp
int rentFunction () {
    int rent;
    do {
        cout << "Rent: " << endl;
        string input;
        if (cin >> input){
            try{
                size_t pos;
                rent = stoi(input, &pos);
                if ((pos == input.size()) && (rent >= 0))
                    break;
            }
            catch (const logic_error &){
            }
            cout << "Please enter a valid number of at least 0" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    while (true);
    return rent;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I hit add comment before I was done typing. 
Thank you for the help!
We haven't covered the try/catch stuff yet and I've got no idea what that logic_error thing is for haha. It seems the solution might be higher than what this class has covered so far.

Comment: @KennyMurrell I did say "*or equivalent*". There are other ways to convert a `string` into an `int` with error checking that is not based on exceptions. Such as `std::strtol()`, `std::sscanf()` with `%n`, `std::istringstream` with checking its available input length after reading from it, etc. Plenty of options.

Comment: @KennyMurrell Or, you can simply stop trying to circumvent the way the streaming system was designed to work.  If the user wants to enter `24a` and apply `24` to `rent` and `a` to `gas`, then just let them do so.

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to do. Get this turned in and move on with my life. Thanks again!